# Ajax an Array of objects to a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, controller

I've been trying to ajax this array to my controller but the data gets set to null when it arrives.

My function:

```
function saveChanges() {
var grid = $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid");
var gridData = grid.dataSource.data();

var dataArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
    dataArray.push({Date: gridData[i].Date, Name: gridData[i].ProductName});
}

$.ajax({
    url: GetUrlRoot() + "Controller/Method",
    data: { gridData: dataArray },
    async: false,
    success: function () {

    },
    error: function () {

    },
    cache: false,
})

grid.saveChanges();
}
```

My Controller:

```
public virtual string Method(List<DateName> gridData)
    {


        return string.Empty;
    }

public class DateName
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The controller recognises that 1 record has been sent, but the values of this record are null.

`Debug.write(dataArray)` returns:

[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: is the action a POST or a GET action?

Comment: The action is a GET.

Comment: That is the problem. Convert the request and controller action to POST and send the data in the body of the request.

Comment: dataArray is still null in the method, I have set both to POST.

Comment: The version makes a big difference, so I had to make some changes to my provided answer. check update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 data: { gridData: dataArray },
```

in the java script would match the following object model in c#

```
public class GridDataObject {
    public List<DateName> gridData { get; set; }
}
```

This however would not match the parameter arguments in

```
public virtual string Method(List<DateName> gridData)
```

So first, update the controller action to expect the desired object model as sent from the client.

A simple example would look like this in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual string Method(GridDataObject data) {
    //...

    var gridData = data.gridData;

    //...

    return string.Empty; //strictly for demo purposes.        
}
```

Secondly, the client needs to send the data using the correct formatting.

```
//...

var url = GetUrlRoot() + "Controller/Method";
var data  = { gridData: dataArray };
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    async: false,
    success: function () {

    }
    error: function () {

    },
    cache: false,
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This works now, is there a specific reason why my way of achieving this was not working?

Comment: @GeorgeB By default a GET will try to serialize the data and add it to the querystring, which wont always bind correctly to the model used by the controller. By posting the data using a matching data object the model binder can initialize and populate the object model correctly with the data sent in the body of the request

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataType: "json"` and `traditional: true`

```
$.ajax({
    url: GetUrlRoot() + "Controller/Method",
    data: dataArray,
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function () {

    },
    error: function () {

    },
    cache: false,
})
```

Comment: Now it returns an empty Array with no properties

Comment: can you post `console.log(dataArray);`  after `for` loop

Comment: Also try `data: dataArray,` instead

Comment: Still the same result

Comment: can you post the  dump of `dataArray` ?

Comment: I tried to get one using debug.write, [object, object] is returned.

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery Ajax section:

change setting data to:

```
data: JSON.stringify(dataArray),
method: 'POST', //or type:'POST' based on jQuery version
...
```

Then you can also change your controller to:

```
public virtual string Method([FromBody]DateName[] gridData){
...
}
```

So with these changes, $.ajax is going to post the JSON to your controller, and your controller is going to parse the JSON from the request body.

Comment: When I used this, gridData was equal to null when it came into the method.